# How to fix Rate Limiter Module Instantiation Error in Play Project

Tags: java, playframework

I am getting a "Module cannot be instantiated error in a RateLimiter" in a newly created play project.
First I thought since it is a new project maybe some configuration is missing, so I checked build.sbt, plugins.sbt but they were fine.

I am not able to figure out what this error is regarding.
I am pasting entire stacktrace for you reference:

```
! @7gf2jmfmi - Internal server error, for (POST) [/testCreateUpdateCandidate] ->
 
play.api.PlayException: Cannot load module[Module [ratelimit.TasksModule] cannot be instantiated.]
        at play.api.inject.Modules$.play$api$inject$Modules$$constructModule(Module.scala:147)
        at play.api.inject.Modules$$anonfun$locate$1.apply(Module.scala:114)
        at play.api.inject.Modules$$anonfun$locate$1.apply(Module.scala:113)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.immutable.HashSet$HashSet1.foreach(HashSet.scala:316)
        at scala.collection.immutable.HashSet$HashTrieSet.foreach(HashSet.scala:972)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.AbstractSet.scala$collection$SetLike$$super$map(Set.scala:47)
        at scala.collection.SetLike$class.map(SetLike.scala:92)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ratelimit.TasksModule
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        at play.api.inject.Modules$$anonfun$locate$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Module.scala:115)
        at play.api.inject.Modules$$anonfun$locate$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Module.scala:115)
        at play.api.inject.Modules$.play$api$inject$Modules$$constructModule(Module.scala:121)
        at play.api.inject.Modules$$anonfun$locate$1.apply(Module.scala:114)
        at play.api.inject.Modules$$anonfun$locate$1.apply(Module.scala:113)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
```

Comment: Show your build.sbt

Comment: Is `ratelimit.TasksModule` a class in your project? Is it referenced in `application.conf`?

Comment: Yes Tim, It is referenced in application.conf. I suspect that something is wrong with that because when I remove the reference from application.conf,  it is not throwing this error.

Comment: Check to make sure that there aren't any typos, including case changes, and that the `TasksModule` class is actually defined in the `ratelimit` package correctly. If you need more help, please upload your project to GitHub, or somewhere else where others can see it.